# How can I improve the throughput of fullwms for a standalone geowebcache?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tomcat, standalone, getmap

Currently I am running an instance of geoserver, as well as a standalone instance of geowebcache. I've been trying to make use of the fullwms feature available in geowebcache, in order to proxy getmap requests to geoserver at higher zoom levels.

What I've found through load testing is that using fullwms dramatically reduces the throughput of uncached getmap requests when compared to making the getmap request
directly to geoserver. I understand that there will be some overhead costs related to proxying requests from one server to another, as well as any processing
that needs to happen within geowebcache. But I never expected such a large difference in throughput.

Using Jmeter I've set up load testing
for 8 concurrent users and compared the throughput between using fullwms and directly calling a getmap request to geoserver.
Getmap requests from geowebcache are never able to exceed 17 requests/second, where getmap requests from geoserver can achieve upwards of 60 requests/second!

Is there any way of optimizing fullwms to achieve a decent throughput or is this feature to intensive for geowebcache to handle?

- I've tried enabling fullwms in the geowebcache-wmsservice-context.xml file, as well as setting the hint to "speed".
- I've tried setting the concurrency in the XML definition of each layer.
- I've tried using a standard HTTP/1.1 connector in tomcat with and without a thread pool Executor.
- I've added ram to the heap and the OS and increased the amount of CPU cores to my geowebcache container with no difference in performance.

Thanks for reading. Using fullwms mode in this manner is of great interest to me from a data management perspective, and for utilization within leaflet
so I'm hoping there is some way of making fullwms more performant.

Answer (score 0):

At 60 r/s on the direct WMS, you're likely already spending a significant chunk of the overall GetMap time encoding the final PNG, with the data retrieval and map painting that are nearing decent performance.

When using fullwms without having the tiles already in cache you have to:

- Get all the metatiles needed to cover the requested areas, as PNGs, from the WMS (so likely requesting an area that's somewhat larger)
- Read those PNGs in memory, slice them down into single tiles, encode the result again in PNG (this builds the tile cache)
- Read the tiles just written on disk, decode them, put together the area covered by the WMS request, eventually rescale, and save the output back in PNG form.

Long story short, it's probably death by PNG encoding/decoding. The fullwms is best used against an existing cache, but even in that case, it may be slower than a well-optimized WMS service due to the input PNG tile decoding (it's slow).

You can try to set up the [in-memory caching](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/storage.html#in-memory-caching) and see if that helps some. You can also try reducing the meta-tiling factors.

A better approach, that requires coding though, is to wire up the [native libdflate](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/libdeflate/index.html) library into the PNG readers and writers. It's used right now only for GeoTIFF, but provides a good speed up there. If you want to go down this path, [check this guide](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-fixes,-improvements-and-new-features-in-GeoServer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems that this kind of setup works best with an integrated geowebcache that has access to geoservers rendering engine.
My tests were done with a metatiling factor of 1x1, and I assumed that by choosing the service strategy of "speed" nothing would be written to disk.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of libdflate, this would be interesting to see if I could get this plugin to work on pngs in geoserver to improve performance.
However, I'm looking to run multiple instances of geoserver behind my geowebcache and even with the performance gain from libdflate, I don't think that
fullwms will be able to make full use of the computing power of my geoserver instances.